# How to make corect sub d topology?

Tags: modeling

I want to make corners like on this picture.
[image: 1.]

Now I have result like this[image]
and like this (not clean)[image]
Now my lowpoly wireframe [image]
Have any ideas how to make clean corners like on the referens?

Answer (score 1):

### Different geometry

It's hard to tell from a single photo the exact geometry of the reference object, but it seems to me that there is no hard edges running up from the vertex of the triangle you are pointing with the black arrows.

The side looks in my opinion flat above that point, while it had different heights after that. I sketched the shape considering the two quads in the bottom left part of the image as if they were displaced from the other surface.

[image]

[image]

Starting from this simple geometry, I then added a few loopcuts and tweaked the crease of some edge to control the curvature of the surface. Here's the final result:

[image]

[image]